# AttributeError: module 'pylint' has no attribute 'checkers'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

When I try to import `pylint.checkers`, I get the following error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d869f1bd3d2f> in <module>
----> 1 pl.checkers

AttributeError: module 'pylint' has no attribute 'checkers'
```

I use *Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]* on *Windows 10 Family - 19041.630* with *IPython 7.19.0*. Installed packages :

```
argon2-cffi            20.1.0
astroid                2.4.2
async-generator        1.10
attrs                  20.3.0
auxlib                 0.0.43
backcall               0.2.0
bleach                 3.2.1
certifi                2020.11.8
cffi                   1.14.3
chardet                3.0.4
colorama               0.4.4
conda                  4.2.7
cryptography           3.2.1
cycler                 0.10.0
decorator              4.4.2
defusedxml             0.6.0
entrypoints            0.3
idna                   2.10
importlib-metadata     2.0.0
ipykernel              5.3.4
ipython                7.19.0
ipython-genutils       0.2.0
ipywidgets             7.5.1
isort                  5.6.4
jedi                   0.17.2
Jinja2                 2.11.2
jsonschema             3.2.0
jupyter                1.0.0
jupyter-client         6.1.7
jupyter-console        6.2.0
jupyter-core           4.7.0
jupyterlab-pygments    0.1.2
kiwisolver             1.3.1
lazy-object-proxy      0.0.0
MarkupSafe             1.1.1
matplotlib             3.3.3
mccabe                 0.6.1
mistune                0.8.4
Naked                  0.1.31
nbclient               0.5.1
nbconvert              6.0.7
nbformat               5.0.8
nest-asyncio           1.4.3
notebook               6.1.5
npyscreen              4.10.5
numpy                  1.19.3
packaging              20.4
pandocfilters          1.4.3
parso                  0.7.1
pickleshare            0.7.5
Pillow                 8.0.1
pip                    20.2.4
prometheus-client      0.9.0
prompt-toolkit         3.0.8
pycparser              2.20
Pygments               2.7.2
pylint                 2.6.1.dev1
pyparsing              2.4.7
PyQt5-sip              12.8.1
pyrsistent             0.17.3
python-dateutil        2.8.1
python-language-server 0.36.1
pywin32                300
pywinpty               0.5.7
PyX                    0.15
PyYAML                 5.3.1
pyzmq                  19.0.2
qdarkstyle             2.8.1
qtawesome              1.0.1
qtconsole              4.7.7
qtpy                   1.9.0
requests               2.25.0
scapy                  2.4.4
Send2Trash             1.5.0
setuptools             50.3.2
shellescape            3.8.1
six                    1.15.0
sphinx                 3.3.0
spyder                 5.0.0a1
spyder-kernels         1.9.4
terminado              0.9.1
testpath               0.4.4
toml                   0.10.2
toolz                  0.11.1
tornado                6.1
traitlets              5.0.5
urllib3                1.26.2
uuid                   1.30
watchdog               0.10.3
wcwidth                0.2.5
webencodings           0.5.1
wheel                  0.35.1
widgetsnbextension     3.5.1
windows-curses         2.2.0
winpython              3.0.20201028
wrapt                  1.12.1
zipp                   3.4.0
```

When I try `dir(pylint)`, I get :

```
In [8]: dir(pylint)
Out[8]:
['__all__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__pkginfo__',
 '__spec__',
 '__version__',
 'run_epylint',
 'run_pylint',
 'run_pyreverse',
 'run_symilar',
 'sys']
```

An other bug : I had the following warning when I install pylint :

```
astroid 2.4.2 requires lazy-object-proxy==1.4.*, but you'll have lazy-object-proxy 0.0.0 which is incompatible.
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: You have to import `pylint.checkers`. The `pylint` module doesn't "export" `checkers`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. I don't know why, but :

```
>>> import pylint.checkers
>>> dir(pylint.checkers)
['BaseChecker', 'BaseTokenChecker', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'base_checker', 'initialize', 'register_plugins', 'table_lines_from_stats']
```

Restart is probbably necessary.

> **EDIT:** See comment.